# PHP Array Output for Parsing in Java?

Tags: java, php, arrays, json, serialization

I have a class, written in Java, that makes a call to a PHP server for information on a series of items. This series should be returned in some sort of collection, such as in an array, a JSON encoded array, etc...

Is there a way that I could have PHP return the collection of data in some way that it could be easily parsed in Java and utilized as either an array or object? For example, if I JSON encode or serialize my PHP array, can it be easily JSON decoded or unserialized and then used as an array?

Comment: Yes. It seems as if you've answered your own question.

Comment: json is about as easy as data interchange gets.

Comment: Yeah, but there isn't any convenient library/built in classes to quickly handle this parsing process. Can you suggest one? The Java library from JSON.org is just that, a huge library that requires countless classes and packages to do something relatively simple. :(

Comment: Have you tried this? http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ And `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` are native functions in PHP.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of PHP's abilities to encode/decode arrays, but I hadn't seen this Java library. Let me look into it! :)

Comment: Hmm... JSON-simple doesn't look like it will *quite* work. I see that I have to include a `JAR` file in the build class-path, something that once I share my source code, my other group members won't be able to do, since they are using a very specific IDE for their portion of the project.

Comment: You need a library for JSON but cannot use any JAR files?  Which IDE are your group members using such that you cannot use any libraries?

Comment: It's the `processing.org` IDE, which to my knowledge, is incredibly watered-down and specific to the framework. Having dug around in the JSON.simple's repo I found their `.java` source files, which we can use with their IDEs. Thanks for your suggestion. It will work after all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your problem is because of the complicated class java has for actually parsing JSON, you may use [JSON.simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple) library.

Here's a snippet of how to decode JSON ([taken from the wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples)):

```
String s="[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]";
Object obj=JSONValue.parse(s);
JSONArray array=(JSONArray)obj;
System.out.println("======the 2nd element of array======");
System.out.println(array.get(1));
System.out.println();

JSONObject obj2=(JSONObject)array.get(1);
System.out.println("======field \"1\"==========");
System.out.println(obj2.get("1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.
PHP has the function http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php to encode arrays in json.

The bigest Proble is that Java is a typed language and PHP is not.

You have to make sure that the values in your PHP array have the correct type or you ay get unexpected results.

Unset values are the most dangerous thing. If your PHP array contains null or false and your Java class expects an empty string you might run into trouble.